# Android Studio giving me Rendering Problems "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant with the design library"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Picture below: (Android Studio won't even let me copy the text)

[image: error screenshot]

I made another app before this and it worked well. I then made a new project and started getting errors like this one for no reason, then I made this project and I CAN'T EVEN RUN THE APP WITHOUT TOUCHING THE CODE. WHAT?

EDIT: I have checked every single file and the theme for all is along the lines of AppCompat, not Holo or anything else;

MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

ACTIVITY_MAIN:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:elevation="6dp"

    android:layout_margin="16dp"

    android:layout_gravity="end"
    />
```

STYLES:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />



<style name="MyStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF255F26</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate.

Comment: As Rubin said add `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"` to all of your themes.Especially app theme, activity theme, toolbar theme and others. Its works fine.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

go to your styles. you will see two sub XML files there, `styles.xml` and `styles.xml (v21)`. check both XML files that the parent is

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

Check your gradle also it contains the proper dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: Thank you I think, I didn't check that folder. I changed it and the rendering problem did not change however, but the app still ran.

I also closed Android Studio and reopened it on another project and for absolutely no reason the rendering problem went away but the app still crashes when it runs. I have literally not made any significant modifications to the XML's